# Is there a way to add Alias to Powershell Cmdlet programmatically?

Tags: powershell, alias, powershell-cmdlet

I am writing custom Powershell cmdlets for my application and I need to provide Aliases to some cmdlets. So lets say I have cmdlet Get-DirectoryListing and I want to add Alias (say 'gdl') to this cmdlet. How can I do this?

The AliasAttribute doesn't work here, since it works only with Properties, Indexers or Field declarations. Also I know we can use Set-Alias command, but don't know where to put it.

Is it possible to programmatically add multiple aliases to a cmdlet?

Comment: Your custom cmdlet is in .net or is a function/script?

Comment: It is in .NET. I am writing classes in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a psm1 file ([powershell module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd878310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) where you specific your dll with yours cmdlets to load and add aliases in this way:

In your module folder ( `Get-ModuleFolder` give a list of all if you have more that the default one, in my example I use the first one) create a **folder with same name of your .dll** 
and a **SameNameOfYourDll.psm1** with this content:

```
Import-module "$((Get-ModulePath)[0])mycustomcmdlet\mycustomcmdlet.dll"
set-alias gdl Get-DirectoryListing -scope Global
```

For more raffinate module building look also at [module manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd878337%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Module manifest is the preffered way for .dll with custom cdmlets](http://kungfukode.blogspot.it/2011/05/write-your-first-powershell-cmdlet-in-c.html).

Comment: Rather then use Get-ModulePath why not just use the automatic variable `$PSScriptRoot` in the module file e.g. `Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\mycustomcmdlet.dll`?

Comment: @KeithHill Yes, Thank you... forgot it because in script doesen't works! But in module works!!!

Comment: FYI, in V3 `$PSScriptRoot` is supposed to work in regular script (.ps1) files as well.

Comment: @KeithHill Yes, I know I  read about that on microsoft connect. Thank for the information.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I solved this using Christians method. I have used New-Alias command instead of Set-Alias though. It works perfectly. I have another question (sort of continuation of this question) posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13598169/1095246