# How to find which Cmdlet Alias was used by user?

Tags: powershell, alias, powershell-cmdlet

Please excuse me if you find this a very lame questions, but since I am learning Powershell I need to ask.

This is a sort of next part of the question posted and answer received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13584769/1095246).

I have a custom cmdlet named Get-DirectoryListing and I added an alias 'gdl' (using New-Alias command in .psm1 file). So user can use either Get-DirectoryListing or gdl to fire the same command. Now I want to detect in my code (.NET, C#) which text was used to execute the command. Lets say if user used alias 'gdl' to execute the command, I want to show message like

> 'This alias is deprecated and shouldn't be used.'

But I do not want to show this message if user uses Get-DirectoryListing to execute the command.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspect the

> this.[MyInvocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.pscmdlet.myinvocation%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).[InvocationName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.invocationname%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

property on your PSCmdlet instance.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks.